# Auto Fill Web Forms in .net-Core

Tags: .net-core, autofill

I am new to .net core.
How can I auto fill forms and submit in dotnet core ?
Please find following sample URLs I want to try

https://mparivahan.in/uyt/?pur_cd=102

Value - 1 = "MH1R"

Value - 2 = "5656"

https://www.filegstrstnow.com/searchGSTTaxpayer
sample Value = "24AADCS0852Q1Z2"

With Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to automate operations in browser. For this purpose **you need a browser automation framework** which can be used in you `.NET Core 2.0` code. Something like [`Selenium WebDriver`](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/webdriver-dotnetcore2/). In this case you code will look like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestWithFirefoxDriver()
{
    using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1")).Send("GJ01RR");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2")).Send("5656");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("form_rcdl:j_idt36")).Click();
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        // Find element with the result to retrieve value, and so on..        
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't check the code above in runtime, it is just for demonstration purposes.

To run Selenium automation code without opening the browser you could use `PhantomJS` driver instead of drivers for real browsers like `FirefoxDriver`. Change this line:

```
using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver())
```

to:

```
using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.I tried Selenium. It works fine in my local machine (as I have already installed Firefox) but on the web server firefox not installed. It gives error as  "Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)"

Comment: I have updated my answer with the note about using PhantomJS driver instead.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I tried it and It worked for me. You saved my lot of time.

Comment: I am glad to help. Feel free to mark it as answer to help other community members quickly indicate it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dmitry Pavlov, 
Instead of Loading whole page,
Can it be possible using just HTTPWebRequest or any other work around which works faster.